# Mapping a drive with powershell in a scheduled task via Start-Job in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, drive

I'm currently trying to run a powershell script on my web service, which maps a drive to a shared folder on another system and copies a folder to it. The strange problem I currently have is that **the script seems to be executed just fine**, however the job in which the script is running doesn't seem to finish properly. Therefore I have to set a timeout for the task to be finished by force, otherwise it won't finish at all. However this is not really what I want, since it can have some nasty side effects if the script takes longer than expected etc. On the other hand I want to have the execution as fast as possible in the given scenario, so I'd like to let the script finished "naturally".

This is my current setup

The C# web service calls the powershell script like this:

```
public Collection<PSObject> executeCommand(String pCommand, String pName)
        {
            // Call the script
            var runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
            runspace.Open();
            var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(pCommand);
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Wait-Job -Name " + pName + " -Timeout 60");
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Receive-Job -Name " + pName);

            return pipeline.Invoke();
        }


String shareArguments = "some stuff here";
        String shareCommandName = "copyFolder";
        String shareCommand = "Start-Job -filepath " + currentDirectory + "\\scripts\\copyFolder.ps1 -ArgumentList " + shareArguments + " -Name " + shareCommandName + " -RunAs32";
        Collection<PSObject> results1 = executeCommand(shareCommand, shareCommandName);

        StreamWriter sharestream = new StreamWriter("D:\\shareoutput.txt");
        foreach (PSObject obj in results1)
        {
            sharestream.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        sharestream.Close();
```

The script itself:

```
   param($sharepath,$shareuser,$sharepassword,$hostname,$sourcefolder)

   # create a credentials object
   $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $sharepassword -AsPlainText -Force
   Write-Output "0"
   $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($shareuser, $secpasswd)
   Write-Output "1"
   # Access the share
   New-PSDrive -Name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $sharepath -Credential $cred
   Write-Output "2"
   # Copy the folder including the file
   Copy-Item $sourcefolder "J:\" -Recurse -Force
   Write-Output "3"
   # Unmap drive
   Remove-PSDrive -Name J
```

When I retrieve the debug output of the job, the output looks like this. So it seems that the New-PSDrive call seems to block here somehow:

```
0
1
```

Any idea what is the cause for this and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance for any hint

Comment: Does it work if you test it against a directory on the local system, without specifying the credentials?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just checked it and with a local folder without credentials it's working fine, the job is finishing quite fast. What could that mean? I mean the original script is properly executed but not finished, so the credentials can't be wrong.

Comment: Any chance you're introducing a "second hop" authentication scenario by using that background job, and it's interfering with that drive mapping?

Comment: I fear I don't know what you mean by a second hop authentication. From what I can say the share is accessed via a domain account and it's also used by other users. Not sure if this answers your question though.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj853299.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the clarificaiton. It seems that this includes remoting, but I'm not doing that (at least not intentionally). The creation of the runspace that executes the job is local on the web server that runs the web service, so I don't think there are more hops involved than the web server and the server on which the share is residing.

Comment: Does it work differently if you just run the script in the new runspace, rather than using the runspace to create a background job?

Comment: I just changed it so that it runs as you mentioned and it indeed makes a difference. When doing it like you said, it's working as it should. Thanks! However, I require some scripts to be executed in 32bit mode, that was one reason why I chose the Start-Job method. Is this possible like this too?

Comment: I don't know. Might have better luck with that as a fresh question.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with  New-PSDrive. First Check your PSCredential object. 
then update the script with

**New-PSDrive** *-Name* J **-PSProvider** FileSystem **-Root** $sharepath **-Credential** $cred ***-Persist***

Perfect article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx